# struts2 load next page without loading css and js file and so on again

Tags: javascript, css, web

I am using struts 2. My home page, has a topbar on top page, and a menu bar on left page. In the center appair a description of my applicatio. The page include the *.css and *.js file and so on.

On click event on any button on left menubar, I call my class action and then load next page. I would not like to load  *.css, *.js, top bar and menu bar again on next page.

I would like use the  *.css and *.js, menubar and topbar loaded first time on the home page.

Is it possible? 
Thank you

Comment: I think Struts Tiles Plugin is an option - e.g. https://www.programcreek.com/2010/03/struts-2-tutorial-series-how-to-insert-tiles-to-your-project/

Comment: why not. I prefer to use ajax in this case.

Comment: Use struts2-jquery plugin, it has tags that generate both css and js files

Comment: Simple answer - No.